# Print all the integers from 1 to 10^n that has the unique digits in it

Tags: java, java-8

I have a working example to print the unique digits(i.e, 123 has unique digits but 11 doesn't)

Below is the code

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
double val = Math.pow(10, n);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
for(int k=1;k<=val;k++){
    String s = Integer.toString(k);
    if(s.length() == 1){
        list.add(k); 
    } else{
        int l = s.length();
        int flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < l; j++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    flag = 1;
                    break; 
                }
            }
        } if(flag == 0){
            list.add(k); 
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

How to efficiently write the above code using java8?

Comment: How do you measure if a given implementation is more efficient than another?

Comment: efficient in the sense to write in limited number of lines using java streams

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be rewritten as next:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, (int) val + 1)
    .filter(
        i -> Integer.toString(i).chars().distinct().count() == Integer.toString(i).length()
    )
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Great, its working, one question what does boxed() will do here?

Comment: it is an IntStream so a Stream of the primitive type int and you want a list so as you cannot have a List<int> you need to box them first to get Integer

Answer (score 2):

Since your only objective is achieving the result with the least possible lines of code, probably this is the winning combo:

```
    int val  = 2; //set your input parameter any way you want, then
```

Do something incomprehensibly twisted solution just to have a **one-liner solution**:

```
    LongStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(Double.valueOf(Math.pow(10, val)).longValue()).filter((value) -> Arrays.stream(Long.valueOf(value).toString().split("")).distinct().count() == Arrays.stream(Long.valueOf(value).toString().split("")).count()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have is fine. The only other real way I could think of you could do this, would to sort the string first, then compare it in pairs

so the number 1436 would sort to 1346, to which you would then compare 1,3  3,4 and 4,6 and find no duplicate numbers.

Efficiency wise this can be done in about O(nlogn) time, as opposed to you current O(n^2) time